# How to get hoverover text to be at the same line-height as the triggering text

Tags: html, css, alignment

I was wondering if you can tell me how I can get a hover over text to be placed where the triggering text is located at? As of now, when you hover over the triggering text, the hover over text fades in on the bottom of the text?

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/yhhzy9vq/5/

CSS:

```
div.centered {
    font-size: 5vh;
}
span.ok {
    opacity:1;
}
span.ok:hover, span.ok:focus {
    opacity:0;
}
span.ok:hover + span.no {
    opacity:1;
}
span.no {
    opacity:0;
}
span.ok, span.no {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}
span {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    font-size: 5vh;
    line-height: 1;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :pseudo-elements and `rgba()` values for `color` and transition the `color` property instead of transitioning the `opacity`.

<kbd>**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yhhzy9vq/9/)**</kbd>

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
div.centered {
  font-size: 5vh;
}
span.ok {
  position: relative;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}
span.ok:after {
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-25%);
  z-index: -1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}
span.ok:hover:after {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)
}
span.ok:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
span {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  font-size: 5vh;
  line-height: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <span data-tooltip="hello hoverover" class="ok">My Link</span><br/>
  <span data-tooltip="hello hoverover" class="ok">My Link</span><br/>
  <span data-tooltip="hello hoverover" class="ok">My Link</span><br/>
  <span data-tooltip="hello hoverover" class="ok">My Link</span><br/>
  <span data-tooltip="hello hoverover" class="ok">My Link</span><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: oh yes, oh yes, oh yes. bingo! thank you @chipChocolate.py, you rock!

Comment: lol sorry give me 1 min, SO won't let me mark your answer as correct

Comment: One thing, if you dont mind: I was playing around with the code, and it seems like if the text is longer or shorter than "My Link" or "Hello Hoverover," the texts will misalign. how can I fix this?

Comment: @kenhimself - Easiest way would be to replace all `span`s with `div`s and add `text-align: center` to `div.ok` and `div.ok:after`; and remove `transform: translateX(-25%)` from `span.of:after`.

Comment: I did follow your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to be working — would you take a look at this please? http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/yhhzy9vq/14/

Answer (score 0):

Try pulling the `span.no` element a little bit to the top by assigning `position:relative` and giving a `z-index:-1`:

```
span.no {
    opacity:0;
    position: relative;
    top: -27px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yhhzy9vq/7/)

Comment: it's a nice solution, but I was wondering if it is possible to completely replace the text, not move it? for example: http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/u7tYE/5061/